# Php / JQuery / Javascript - Select Parent child dependency

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

[image: Show Sub Category based on Category]
 - - Check out this image.

I want that when someone selects any category then the sub category displays choices based on that particular category that was selected. I'm learning PHP/MySQL but I know the basics of Javascript. Can any teach me in a simple way how it can be done with JavaScript or JQuery?

Categories and sub categories are showing perfectly in the dropdown but are showing all the Sub-Categories and Categories.

```html
<div>
  <label>Category</label>
  <select name="category">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
    <?php
    $cdata = $dbobj->getCategories(0);
    while($crow = mysql_fetch_array($cdata)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $crow["categoryid"]; ?>"><?php echo $crow["category_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Sub Category</label>
  <select name="subcategory">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
    <?php
    $scdata = $dbobj->getSubCategories(0);
    while($scrow = mysql_fetch_array($scdata)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $scrow["subcategoryid"]; ?>"><?php echo $scrow["subcategory_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Thanks

> Categories & Sub Categories

Men

- Clothes
- Shoes

Women

- Jewelry
- Sarees
- Shoes

Kids

- Toys
- Clothes

Books

- Language
- Fiction

What I want is - whenever someone chooses the category **Men**, only two subcategories, **Clothes** and **Shoes** show up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change selected value of dynamically generated dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256265/change-selected-value-of-dynamically-generated-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery :

```
$(function(){
    $(".category option").click(function(){
        $(".category").parent().css("display", "none"); // Targetting the parent and hide
        $(".subcategory").parent().css("display", "block"); // Targetting the parent and show
    });
    $(":not(.category option)").click(function(){
        // If click on other thing than category option then show
        $(".category").parent().css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

**EDIT** : Added the possibility to return to category